# Dispatch reducers from another slice in Redux/Redux Toolkit

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

### The Setup

In my backend, I have a `Musician` model which can have many `Instrument`s or `Song`s. The rest API has separate routes to get all Musicians, get all the Instruments for a musician, get all the Songs for a musician, etc.

My root state looks like this:

```
musicians: [],
instruments: [],
songs: []
```

I then have 3 Redux Toolkit "slices" that manage those respective parts of state. For example, `instrumentsSlice` has an async thunk called `fetchInstruments` that calls the rest API to fetch instruments *for a specific musician*, then is fulfilled in extraReducers:

```
extraReducers: {
[fetchInstruments.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
   return action.payload.map(instrument => {
      instrument.id = nextInstrumentId++;
      return instrument;
  });
},
  ....
}
```

On the page for a specific musician: `fetchInstruments` and `fetchSongs` are dispatched, which call their respective APIs that update the state. The Selectors I use then filter only the Instruments or Songs that match the particular Musician ID for that page.

### The Problem

Up to this point, I've been able to get away with using these 3 separate slices. Now, I want to create a dashboard where I can view summary information for *all* Musicians. I realized that it wouldn't make sense to call 3 XHR requests per every Musician listed, so I created a single new rest route that returns the information nested for all musicians, `fetchAllMusicianData`, i.e.:

```
musicians: [
 {
   name:,
   instruments: [],
   songs: []
 },
 ...
 ]
```

### The Question

Somehow, I need to get this nested Musician/Instrument/Song data into my state tree. However, ideally, I  don't want to duplicate logic that exists in the `fetchInstruments` or `fetchSongs` reducers (such as creating local ids in my `extraReducers` code above).

Is there some way that when the `fetchAllMusicianData` call is fulfilled, I can call each of those other slices to run their methods like `fetchInstruments.fulfilled`? Is there some way I need to abstract updating this information? Or, should I be organizing my state in a different way?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Let's get one thing out of the way first. You should not increase your ids like this in general:

```
extraReducers: {
[fetchInstruments.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
   return action.payload.map(instrument => {
      instrument.id = nextInstrumentId++;
      return instrument;
  });
},
  ....
}
```

As `nextInstrumentId` is an external variable, you are introducing a side effect here - so if you were to replay your actions using the devtools (stuff like for examples "skipping" an action will replay them from the start), you would get different ids a second time. And if you had other actions that referenced those ids (or local state or a url parameter etc.), that reference would break.

So, those ids would either need to be generated based only on information available in the reducer or even better, directly in your `createAsyncThunk` call.
Doing such a side effect there is perfectly fine.

Now, back to the question at hand:

My suggestion would be to change the return value of your `fetchInstruments` so that it shares the same (partial) structure as your `fetchAllMusicianData` asyncThunk.

So,

```js
const fetchInstruments = createAsyncThunk('fetchInstruments', () => {
  // get the data:
  const fetched = fetchData();
  // apply some ids
  const instruments = fetched.map(instrument => ({ ...instrument, id: nextInstrumentId++ }))
  // return it as part of an object
  return { instruments }
}
```

Then do the same for your `fetchAllMusicianData`:

```js
const fetchAllMusicianData = createAsyncThunk('fetchAllMusicianData', () => {
  // get the data apply some ids, you get the gist

  // return it as an object
  return { instruments, songs, name }
}
```

And now you can have all slice just handle `fetchInstruments` and `fetchAllMusicianData` (or `fetchSongs` and `fetchAllMusicianData` etc.) the same.

Use the extraReducers builder notation with a [matcher](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/matching-utilities) for that:

```js
extraReducers(builder) {
  builder
    .addMatcher(
      isFulfilled(fetchInstruments, fetchAllMusicianData),
      (state, action) => {
        // or whatever other logic you need here
        return action.payload.instruments;
      }
    )
}
```

and that should do it in the end.